# Finding zeros of a function

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, roots

I need to find when $f(x)=0$, where:
\begin{equation}
f(x)=1-\dfrac{k}{x}-\dfrac{k}{3}\dfrac{e^{-ax}}{x}+\dfrac{4k}{3}\dfrac{e^{-bx}}{x}
\end{equation}
Here, $k$, $a$ and $b$ are positive constants. I think this problem analytically is impossible, but I really don't know. I've tried to use Mathematica but it doesn't give any answer and I'm pretty desperate.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Well, do you need a closed form solution or is a numerical solution good enough?

Comment: @DavidCian What do you mean by closed form? I think this problem doesn't have analytic solution, so numerical would be great. Although, I haven't been able to solve it numerically.

Comment: A numerical solution possible only if the values of $a,b,k$ are given. In any case you can simplify the equation multiplying the function by $\frac{3x}k$.

Comment: After multiplying by $3x/k$, we get one solution $x=0$ (not a solution of the original, of course). Are there any other real solutions?  Sometimes there are, other times, not.

Comment: @user Yeah, that's the problem. I have $a$, $b$ and $k$ arbitrary so I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, that's because of multiplying artificially by $x$ and giving the equation a new root. I think there must be some real solution, but I have no idea about how can I obtain it.

Comment: For example: in case $a=2,b=1,k=1$ there is no nonzero solution.  In case $a=1,b=2,k=1$ there is a solution $x \approx 0.9215$.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks! Is there a way of fixing, for example, $a$ and $b$, and obtain $x$ in terms of $k$?

Comment: Even with ${a=1,b=2,k=1}$, Maple found no closed form for $x$.

Comment: @GEdgar Damn, thank you so much again. This seems to be a terrible problem with so many DOF.

Comment: Better notations in a separate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*A priori*, I suppose that $x=0$ cannot be an interesting zero  of function
$$f(x)=1-\dfrac{k}{x}-\dfrac{k}{3}\dfrac{e^{-ax}}{x}+\dfrac{4k}{3}\dfrac{e^{-bx}}{x}$$ So, consider
$$g(x)=x\,f(x)=x-k-\dfrac{k}{3}e^{-ax}+\dfrac{4k}{3}e^{-bx}$$

We have
$$g(0)=0 \qquad g'(0)=1+\frac{1}{3} k (a-4 b)\qquad g''(0)=-\frac{1}{3} k \left(a^2-4 b^2\right)$$ So, if $g'(0)<0$ and $g''(0) >0$, there is a chance to find something.

Expanding $g(x)$ as a Taylor series around $x=0$, we have
$$g(x)=x \left(\frac{1}{3} k (a-4 b)+1\right)-\frac{1}{6} x^2 \left(k \left(a^2-4
   b^2\right)\right)+\frac{1}{18} k x^3 \left(a^3-4 b^3\right)-\frac{1}{72} x^4
   \left(k \left(a^4-4 b^4\right)\right)+O\left(x^5\right)$$ Dividing by $x$ and using series reversion
$$x=t+\frac{\left(a^3-4 b^3\right)}{3 \left(a^2-4 b^2\right)}t^2 +\frac{ \left(5
   a^6+12 a^4 b^2-64 a^3 b^3+12 a^2 b^4+80 b^6\right)}{36 \left(a^2-4
   b^2\right)^2}t^3+O\left(t^{4}\right)$$ where $t=\frac{2k( a -4 b) +6}{(a^2 -4 b^2) k}$

For the case $a=1,b=2,k=1$ considered by @GEdgar, the above gives as an *estimate*
$$x=\frac{5605384}{6834375}=0.820175$$ which is not fantastic. But, starting with this estimate, Newton method will work like a charm (one single iteration for $8$ exact significant figures !).
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.82017507 \\
 1 & 0.92826114
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Just for the fun of it, I built the series expansion up to $O\left(x^{15}\right)$ (this is just ridiculous !) and used series reversion (I shall not report any formula here since they are monsters).

For the worked case, the *estimate* is
$$x=\frac{116953055942942882914859816106777623661064}{126941147255319208068560063838958740234375}$$ which is $0.921317$.

Comment: This is just amazing, you did it in the general case with the constants! That's exactly what I wanted! The last edit is very useful, it shows clearly the significance of adding higher powers of the expansion. Just one thing I don't trivially see, why do we need $g'(0)<0$ and $g''(0)>0$? Thank you so much for the comment and the effort :)

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles. Since we start from $0$, we need that the function looks like a parabola (decrease and then increase). May be, you could accept my answer. I hope to do something better. Cheers

Comment: Perfect, now it makes complete sense to me. Again, thanks a lot for your answers and time. Cheers mate.

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, can you give me some details about how does the parameter $t$ appears? I've tried to use InverseSeries[s,x] in Mathematica but it gives me an expansion in terms of $x$.

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles. Ping me tomorrow morning and open a chat room.

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles. I am here !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120361/discussion-between-claude-leibovici-and-axionlike-particles).

Comment: I have been thinking deeply about the conditions $g'(0)<0$ and $g''(0)>0$ in order to obtain a solution. I have found that the combination $k=3,a=2,b=1.5$ does not satisfy  $g'(0)<0$ and $g''(0)>0$, nevertheless this combination it gives a possible $x>0$ root at $x\approx 3$. Is there a way to fix the possible values of the parameters $k,a,b$ in order to obtain a possible root $x>0$? Since the above criteria seems to don't contemplate some values as the example I gave above.

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles. I do not agree. With this set of parameters $g'(0)=-3$ and $g''(0)=+5$ and the estimate is $\frac{12939}{6250}\sim 2.070$. The first iterate of Newton method is $3.07478$.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I've got a mistake when simplyfing further the inequalities and made a wrong conclusion. Your analysis is correct and there exists a real solution only when $g'(0)<0$ and $g''(0)<0$. Thanks!

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles. $g''(0) \color{red}{>}0$. I am still working this interesting problem.

Comment: Sorry, It was a typo. The condition of the post is the correct one, hahaha. I'm glad you find it interesting! The truth is that it has a surprising hidden beauty that I find completely unexpected.

Comment: What about the combination $k=1,a=5,b=2$? This gives a solution around $x=0.65>0$ and verifies $g'(0)>0$ and $g''(0)<0$, this completely broke me now in order to set some range to the possible values of $k,a,b$.

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles. For this case, $g'(0)=0$. When this is the case, before series reversion you need to divide the series by $x^2$ and not $x$. I am still working.

Answer (score 0):

*I prefer to add another answer for better notations.*

Let $$b=\lambda\, a \qquad \text{and} \qquad t=2\,\frac{ a\, k \,(4 \lambda -1)-3}{a^2 \,k \,\left(4 \lambda ^2-1\right)}$$
Now
$$x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Bigg[\frac a {4 \lambda ^2-1}\Bigg]^{n-1}\, \frac{P_{n}(\lambda)}{c_n}\,\, t^n$$ where the first $c_n$ are
$$\{1,3,36,270,6480,45360,2721600,\cdots \}$$ and the $P_n$ are polynomials of degree $3(n-1)$ in $\lambda$. The very first are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & P_n(\lambda) \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 4 \lambda ^3-1 \\
 3 & 80 \lambda ^6+12 \lambda ^4-64 \lambda ^3+12 \lambda ^2+5 \\
 4 & 1088 \lambda ^9+456 \lambda ^7-1800 \lambda ^6+618 \lambda ^5-222 \lambda
   ^4+450 \lambda ^3-114 \lambda ^2-17 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using this notations, it will be quite simple to generate as many terms as required.

**Edit**

After a comment about the case $(k=1,a=5,b=2)$, I realise that the first condition is not $g'(0) <0$ but $g(0) \leq 0$. If we face the case where $g'(0)=0$, the problem is a bit different.
$$g'(0)=1+\frac{a k}{3}-\frac{4 a \lambda  k}{3}\implies k=\frac{3}{a (4 \lambda -1)}$$ In such a case, the series expansion of $g(x)$ around $x=0$ starts with a term in $x^2$.

$$g(x)=\frac{x^2} {4\lambda-1}\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{a^{n+1} \left(4 \lambda ^{n+2}-1\right)}{(n+2)!}\, x^n$$

The inversion of the sum does not make any problem but leads to other polynomials in $$t=\frac{3 \left(4 \lambda ^2-1\right)}{a \left(4 \lambda ^3-1\right)}$$

Comment: Very interesting! This would work perfectly. Thanks again, cheers!

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles. Amazing, isn't it ? I generated a lot of the $P_n$ but they are loooong !

Comment: It really is, it's very nice to see how with the change $b=\lambda a$ the expression becomes really tractable! Yes, when n becomes a bit large the polinomial functions must be terrible, but I hopefully think few orders will be needed!

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles. If $b>a$ I have an explicit estimate of the solution. For the worked case, it is $0.796812$. If this is of any interest, just tell.

Comment: Of course it is of interest! All your contributions have been amazing and that's an interesting particular case.

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles. Have a look at my edit for the case $g'(0)=0$

Comment: I still don't see clearly the condition. For example, for another case $k=3,a=4,b=1$ we have $g'(0)>0$ and $g''<0$ and there is a solution around $x = 2.75$. This new case doesn't verify the new condition $g'(0)\leq 0$ and the older $g''>0$, so I still don't know how to set ranges to the values $k,a,b$ in order to have a solution $x>0$. Thank you for the edit!

Answer (score 0):

*Another point.*

We have
$$g(x) >x-\frac{4 }{3}k+\frac{4}{3} k e^{-b x}$$ which means that the solution $x$ we are looking for has, as an upper bound,
$$x_{\text{max}} = \frac{4}{3} k+\frac 1 b W\left(-\frac{4}{3} b k e^{-\frac{4 b k}{3}}\right)$$
For the worked example in answers $(a=1,b=2,k=1)$, the iterations would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 n & \text{Newton} & \text{Halley} & \text{Householder} \\
 0 & 1.21624210 & 1.21624210 & 1.21624210 \\
 1 & 0.94495684 & 0.92825892 & 0.92322342 \\
 2 & 0.92178566 & 0.92152597 & 0.92152579 \\
 3 & 0.92152582 & 0.92152579 &  \\
 4 & 0.92152579 & & 
\end{array}
\right)$$

For the worked example in comments $(a=2,b=\frac 32,k=3)$, the iterations would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 n & \text{Newton} & \text{Halley} & \text{Householder} \\
 0 & 3.9899342 & 3.9899342 & 3.9899342 \\
 1 & 2.9756564 & 2.9644279 & 2.9585726 \\
 2 & 2.9552065 & 2.9551855 & 2.9551854 \\
 3 & 2.9551854 & 2.9551854 & 
\end{array}
\right)$$

From a purely numerical point of view, this could be a quite efficient solution using even much higher order methods (the successive derivatives of $g(x)$ being so unexpensive to compute.

For example, using a method of order $6$ gives as a first iterate $x=2.9552614$.

**Edit**

What we can also do is to use one iteration of Newton, Halley or Householder (even higher order method) around $x=k$. This does not make any problem with a CAS.

For the worked cases, this will give with Newton
$$x=\frac{128-36 e-117 e^2+18 e^3+18 e^4}{64-12 e-95 e^2+12 e^3+18 e^4}\sim 0.921758$$
$$x=\frac{16-97 e^{3/2}+156 e^3+26 e^6-80 e^{15/2}+6 e^{12}}{4-23 e^{3/2}+36 e^3+8
   e^6-24 e^{15/2}+2 e^{12}}\sim 2.955188$$

and this will be better and better when $\Delta=(4 e^{-b k}-e^{-a k})$ will close to $0$. For the first case $\Delta=\frac{4-e}{e^2}\sim 0.173462$; for the second $\Delta=\frac{4 e^{3/2}-1}{e^6}\sim 0.041957$. This seems to explain the results.

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you so much. The upper bound for x is very curious too.

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles. Be patient ! I shal have more.